# Strange javascript prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

JavaScript gurus, here is a puzzle for you:

```
function aFunc(){}
function bFunc() {}
aFunc.prototype = bFunc.prototype;
a = new aFunc();
console.log(a instanceof bFunc); //true!
```

Why is `a` instance of `bFunc`?

I could understand this if it was like so:

```
function aNext(){}
function bNext(){}
aNext.prototype = new bNext();
a = new aNext();
console.log(a instanceof bNext);
```

..but with prototypes it seems very strange to me. Practical applications of prototypal code above you can find in Professional JavaScript for Web Developers book (ch 6, last pages).

**Edit:**
Thanks Blender, but here respectively comes new riddle:
now if we have 2 objects that are inherited from single same object they are instanceof each other (but they are completely different)!

```
function Horse(){} //class chain can be very long
function Pig(){}
Horse.prototype = Object.prototype;
Pig.prototype = Object.prototype;
a = new Pig();
console.log(a instanceof Horse); //true!
```

How can we solve issue? How can I determine that pig is not a horse, if they all are animals (have same prototypes in the past)?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: your Horse and Pig constructors have an identical prototype, so thats why 'a' is an instanceof Horse. Make sure to use 'new Object()' instead of Object.prototype!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the `prototype` property of a constructor.

So in your case, it tests whether `bFunc.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `a`. Since `bFunc.prototype === a.prototype`, it'll return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
pig_instance.prototype = Object.prorotype = horse_instance.prototype, so pig and horse comes from same prototype, instanceof checks this and returns TRUE.